# Skylinkjs with Typescript

Tags: typescript, npm

A typescript amateur here. I am trying to use SkylinkJS with typescript language. What is the standard way of using npm library with TypeScript.

The link to Skylinkjs npm module is https://github.com/Temasys/SkylinkJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it in the following steps:

1. Install npm package ([skylinkjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/skylinkjs))
2. Locate and install definitions (d.ts files) for skylinkjs. Here might be a problem as it does not look like they are available. If so - you can work with skylink as you would in pure javascript using ambient declarations, for example:

> ```
> declare var Skylink;
> var Demo = Demo || {};
> Demo.Skylink = new Skylink();
> //...
> ```

Or create your own type definitions skylink to leverage the typescript types checking etc. More info here: [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#writing-dts-files-guidelines-and-specifics)

3. Have fun writing your app with typescript.
4. After you are done with #3 - compile your ts files into JS using tsc compiler or (if you are using gulp/grunt) - corresponding plugins.
5. Reference your compiled JS files in html page or use some module loader (SystemJS) to load them dynamically. Use hero app at angular.io as a sample.
6. Optionally you can bundle your app into neat small package with bundling tools like webpack or systemjs builder.

Comment: Hi Amid, if I want to create my own type script definition file, where should I start from ?

Comment: You can start from here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#writing-dts-files, or here: http://peter.grman.at/how-to-write-typescript-definition-files/. There is plenty info on this topic in google.

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported [as of the moment as stated in here](https://github.com/Temasys/SkylinkJS/issues/205) but feel free to contribute to the github repo for TypeScript support.

https://github.com/Temasys/SkylinkJS